# popup pdf viewer with EXT JS

Tags: extjs

I want to create a popup pdf viewer with ext js.
I have tried some panel examples like :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
   Ext.widget('panel', {
        title: 'My PDF',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        items: {
            xtype: 'component',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none',
                src: './test.pdf'
            }
        },
        renderTo: 'selection'
    });
});
```

I want Some think similar to [this](http://sunbox.github.io/st2_pdf_panel/demo/SimpleViewer/)

the difference between my need and this one is that i want a close and print button on the top right og the screen. and i dont need a pagination

Any leads ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
var showss = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window' {
                            title: 'PDF Content',
                            width: 400,
                            height: 600,
                            modal   : true,
                            closeAction: 'hide',
                            items: [{ 
                                     xtype: 'component',
                                     html : '<iframe src="./test.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>',
                                  }]
                        });
  showss.show();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this example does not look like the one i've posted in the example (The link).

Any other leads ?